# PREV, BASE, or COMMITTED revision keywords are invalid for URL while reintegrating a branch

Tags: svn, merge

I have branched my trunk (at a previous revision) and implemented/commited a new feature and implemented part of another feature locally to the branch.
I now need to reintegrate the finished feature to the trunk.

I `svn cp branches/completedfeature branches/uncompletedfeature` to get the partially completed feature in its own branch.
I then `svn revert -R .` everything in the first branch so it is up to date.

Now when I `svn merge --reintegrate ../../branches/completedfeature` from the trunk, I get this cryptic (to me) error:

```
PREV, BASE, or COMMITTED revision keywords are invalid for URL while reintegrating a branch
```

Both the trunk and the completed feature branch are up to date with no local changes.
What is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like I branched it poorly/wrong. I haven't figured out how to fix this the right way, for anyone that is in this situation here is how I got my changes in to the trunk preserving most of the history of this short-lived branch:

Find all your files that changed `diff -ur trunk branch`.  Make sure you look through the diff's as any changes in the trunk that are not in the branch will get reverted, so ignore those files or if there are changes in a file in both tree's make sure to edit the diff manually later.

Copy any new files with svn to preserve their history `svn cp branch/path/file trunk/path/file`

Now you just need the changes in the files that did not change.  You cannot do a two source merge because (at least in svn 1.7 in cygwin) it will delete and then add the file, wiping out the history.  The option I chose was to build/apply a patch and make a commit message about what happened.

There are [much](http://linux.byexamples.com/archives/163/how-to-create-patch-file-using-patch-and-diff/) [better](http://kernelnewbies.org/FAQ/HowToApplyAPatch) places to learn about patching, but below is what I did. Keep in mind you will need to manually fix your merge issues if you have files that got changed in both tree's.

Build your patch with `diff -u trunk/path/file branch/path/file >> patch.patch`
Do this for each file, or pass in the recursive flag again and have diff do the hard work.

Do a dry run to make sure the patch works and gets the right files patched `patch -p0 --dry-run < patch.patch`
Then patch it `patch -p0 < patch.patch`

Then make sure the project builds and check it in.

Leaving this question open in hopes someone knows the real answer.

Answer (score 6):

I had this error.

Your question was almost the only google result ([here is a description of the keywords](http://svn.uni-koblenz.de/svn-manual/#svn.tour.revs.keywords)).

I had a long branch with other branches merged into it... the patch process was going to be long and difficult.  So despite that [This section of the SVN redbood](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html#svn.branchemerge.basicmerging.reintegrate) suggests that you should merge two working copies, i optimistically tried reintegrating from the URL and it worked!

```
cd myLocalTrunk
svn merge --reintegrate https://svn.blah.blah/blah/blah/branches/myBranch
svn ci -m "reintegrating myBranch into trunk"
```

Answer (score 0):

In general there is no need to use patch-files here - any "-c x" or "-r x:y" range is actually a changeset, i.e. a kind of patch that may be applied. Let's make a complete example, so initially

```
svn copy trunk/path/file branch/path/file
```

and after that one can work on trunk. Now you need to know the revision-range to apply the changes to the target - since the revision number is global, you can ask both files, for example

```
svn info trunk/path/file 
# 35

svn info branch/path/file
# 27
```

This is the range to use, now you can say

```
svn merge -r 27:35 trunk/path/file branch/path/file
```

You may think of it as if it is creating a patch file internally for the range 27:35 being applied to the target. As long as this is only file-to-file you can not even get a tree-conflict (think of renamed files in a directory merge).

Comment: Shouldn't it be `svn merge -r 27:35 branch/path/file trunk/path/file`?

Comment: My example is a downmerge, so it is technically correct, but you are right in that the original question asked for an upmerge.